# shared ssh private key passphrases

Tags: ssh-keys

I am performing some security fixes in a RedHat server and I need to confirm that the SSH private key passphrases are assigned and not shared.

I know some have null passphrases but for the ones that do have one, how can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question can do with some clarification.

A private key should be associated with a single user - and the passphrase should be set by that user to something only they know, and is fairly long.

I'd argue that they should be assigned by the user who has the private key, and not imposed on them. It is possible for them to change the passphrase.

In an ideal world, the private key itself should be generated by the user, and never transmitted (but in practice many people lack the knowledge to handle this, do unfortunately this rule gets broken a lot).

You can not check if multiple people/ entities have the same passphrase unless you have access to the private keys. If you have access to the private keys, you need to revoke the keys and reissue in such a way you don't - because others will have them as well.